# Importing data sets in R Markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

So, after doing some research and help from some of you, I'm starting to understand how R Markdown works. I've essentially copied and pasted my entire R script into my R Markdown script. When I try to run Knitr, I get an error saying it isn't able to execute the `file.choose()` command. Since, I'm gathering data from 6 different .csv files, this is rather worrysome.

Are there any workarounds or am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Let me know if you need any more details. Thanks.

Comment: Put in the path to the file.

Comment: you can't prompt the user for input in an R markdown document. Why aren't you using paths to the data files?

Comment: good question, we were taught to just use file choose but i'll fix that.

Comment: However, you can prompt the user to chose a file in an interactive document (such as an Rmarkdown document that uses shiny - but this will be your next step after learning Rmarkdown basics first :) )

Comment: We can use `file.choose()` in R Markdown. Are you choosing multiple files at once or one by one and also which machine you are using Windows?

Comment: I hope by chance you did not miss selection of file or canceled it, otherwise code wont run. Did you get the dialog boxes for each of those 6 csv files?